# Rationale behind not providing / providing <T> before return type of a method/constructor in Java for Generic classes

Tags: java, generics

What is the rationale behind not providing  / providing  before return type of a method/constructor in Java for Generic classes?

I cannot get my head around it.

Sometimes it wants it and sometimes not. Do we ever need it for constructors?
The rules seem to be random and cannot find a logical explanation for it.

Answer (score 2):

`<T>` in the method definition means that the type is defined in the method signature, and used only within that method.

Comment: Also, you can bound the generic parameter. For instance defining it like: < T extends Observable >

Answer (score 2):

Put `<T>` before the return type of a method when you want a generic associated with that method, instead of the containing class.

```
class Foo {
    // T is associated with the method
    <T> T stuff(T x) ...
}

class Bar<T> {
    // T is associated with the class
    T stuff(T x) ...
}

class Baz<T> {
    // S is associated with the method, T with the class
    <S> T stuff(S x) ...
    <S> S otherStuff(T x) ...
}

class WTF<T> {
    // Legal, but redundant
    <T> T stuff(T x) ...
}
```

Constructors are no different. It is possible to put generics in constructors, as in

```
class Weird {
    // T is associated with the constructor only
    <T> Weird(T arg) ...
}
```

This would be unusual, though. It is much more common to see constructors use class-level generics, as in

```
class Normal<T> {
    // T is associated with the class, as usual
    Normal(T arg) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes it wants it and sometimes
>   not.

In the following case, it is not necessary, because the generic type is declared/defined as part of the class definition:

```
public class Example<T> {

    public T generateItem() { return null; };

}
```

In the following case, it is necessary, because the generic type is **NOT** declared/defined as part of the class definition (or elsewhere):

```
public class Example {

    public <T> T generateItem() { return null; };

}
```

The rule is: is it declared somewhere in the context or not? That's it!